# can't target regions with code > 9428 on #Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using #Linkedin `API v2` to post on a company page but I'm having some problems when targeting locations where the code is `> 9428`.

making a call to: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares`

using the following body:

```
{
  "owner": "urn:li:organization:{ORGANIZATION_ID}",
  "text": {
    "text": "this is a test"
  },
  "subject": "No Title",
  "distribution": {
    "linkedInDistributionTarget": {
      "locations": [
        "urn:li:region:9429"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get a weird error message:

```
{
    "message": "CompanyValidation failed: Unable to get products for company {ORGANIZATION_ID}",
    "status": 400
}
```

but if I change the region to be any less than 9429 (9428 for example) it goes all as expected.

Any ideas if I'm doing something wrong? Thanks in advance

(I tried #Linkedin customer support but they said they're not trained to reply this kind of question and asked me to post on here)